# added SSL does not work for AWS Load Balancer using ACM

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, elastic-load-balancer

I have a AWS **LoadBalancer** which created using `Kube`, `Kops` and `AWS`.
protocl type for the **ELB** is **tcp**. this work fine for `http` requests, means I can access my site with **http://testing.example.com**. Now I tried to add **SSL** for this **ELB** using **ACM** `(Certificate manager)`. I added my Domain details `example.com` and `*.example.com` by requesting a **public Certificate**. it created successfully and domain validation is also success.

> Then I tried to add this ssl to my ELB like below.

- went to my ELB and selected the ELB.
- Then went to Listeners tab and Added SSL to it like below.

[image]

and **ELB** description is like below.

[image]

I cannot access the https://testing.example.com, it hangs for few minutes and nothing happens. what is going on here. hope your help with this.

Answer (score 2):

In the Listener configuration, you are forwarding the default HTTP port `80` to port `30987` on the back-end server. So this tells me that the back-end server is listening for HTTP requests on port `30987`.

You then added an SSL listener on the default port `443` but you are forwarding that to port `443` on the back-end server. Do you have something on your back-end listening on port `443` in addition to `30987`?

The most likely fix for this is to change the SSL listener on the load balancer to forward to port `30987` on the back-end by setting that as the "Instance Port" setting.

Comment: hi @Mark B I tried it. then it says `Failed to create listener on port: 443. Listeners can't talk to InstancePort 30987 with secure and insecure protocols at the same time`

Comment: then I tried by adding `30987` as `Instance Port` and `Instance Protocol` as `TCP` and `Load Balancer Protocol` and `Load Balancer Port` kept as it is `SSL` and `443`. it allows me to add it, but the same result. it doesn't work. took lots of time to response and fail.

Comment: I'm not sure why it is giving you that error message but I think you need to change the first listener to HTTP instead of TCP. Then change the HTTPS back to point to `30987`. Obviously using instance port of `443` is **NOT** going to work since you don't have anything listening on that port on the back-end server.

Comment: changed to `HTTP` then default port `80` is working fine. then added `HTTPS` and  `Instance Protocol` as `HTTPS` with `30987`. then it says `Failed to create listener on port: 443. Listeners can't talk to InstancePort 30987 with secure and insecure protocols at the same time`. then added `HTTPS` with `Instance Protocol` as `HTTP` with the port `30987`. it allows me to add but same as above. hanging for lot time and timeout. ;)

Comment: I guess I'm leaving out details because they are obvious to me, but instance protocol and instance port should be HTTP and `30987` for both of the listeners configured on your load balancer. Are you saying with that configuration it times out?

Answer (score 0):

If your backend application (that sits behind the ELB) only listens on HTTP port `30987` then you need some layer of TLS termination before your app server.
More food for thought on this approach:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30403/should-ssl-be-terminated-at-a-load-balancer

Or you need to tweak your backend app server to also listen on an HTTPS / TLS context, in a different port (which you must map in your ELB configuration).

BTW, I would also suggest to switch to and ALB or an NLB.
More info: https://medium.com/cognitoiq/how-cognitoiq-are-using-application-load-balancers-to-cut-elastic-load-balancing-cost-by-90-78d4e980624b

Once you finish the setup of whatever suggestion you picked, run `curl -k -I https://testing.example.com/` to check whether of not you are getting blocked by the ELB.